# How to use ErrorHandlingDeserializer2 to handle exceptions during deserialization

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm using spring-kafka - 2.2.7.RELEASE and trying to understand how can i configure ErrorHandlingDeserializer2 to handle exceptions during deserialization and logs/send them DLT. I'm setting my consumer configs as per the below documentation
https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#error-handling-deserializer.

Here my question is, how do we grab the exception and the consumer record which is failed during deserialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider to upgrade to Spring for Apache Kafka `2.3.1`.

Here is a Doc how to do your requirement: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#dead-letters

> Starting with version 2.3, when used in conjunction with an `ErrorHandlingDeserializer2`, the publisher (read as `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer`) will restore the record `value()`, in the dead-letter producer record, to the original value that failed to be deserialized. Previously, the `value()` was null and user code had to decode the `DeserializationException` from the message headers. In addition, you can provide multiple `KafkaTemplate` s to the publisher; this might be needed, for example, if you want to publish the `byte[]` from a `DeserializationException`, as well as values using a different serializer from records that were deserialized successfully. Here is an example of configuring the publisher with `KafkaTemplate` s that use a String and byte[] serializer:

So, I believe this doc even gives you a clue how to proceed in the version `2.2.x`.

By the way we always recommend to upgrade at least to the latest point release in the generation. Currently that one is `2.2.10`:  https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#learn

Comment: I've a question here- my actual intention is to differentiate and handle two major types of errors at the consumer level 1. Handle the records which failed during deserialization - We don't want to have any retry for these because it's of no use. 2. Handle the message which were failed during actual processing, and we want to have retry for these records. With all these things in place, I'm wondering how can I use RecoverCallBack in conjunction with  ErrorHandlingDeserializer2 and DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer. Please suggest.

Comment: Please, don't mix responsibilities. The `ErrorHandlingDeserializer2` is really for deserialization problem. Those failed records don't reach your listener at all. For listener side we provide a `KafkaListenerErrorHandler` and that one really can deal with retries. See more in Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#annotation-error-handling

Comment: I see your point. All I'm trying to understand is, can we have both ErrorHandlingDeserializer2 to handle deserialization problem and RecoverCallBack to handle the message after all the retries are exhausted.

Comment: Yes, you can. One for deserialization problems and another in the `KafkaListenerErrorHandler` for any other problems. Although I would still distinguish those different problem types to different Deal Letter Topics...

Comment: I agree that we should have different DLTs for these and that's the plan. Thanks for the details